# Typescript type casting when destructuring

Tags: typescript, lodash

Let's assume this

```
{foo, bar} = groupBy(arg);
```

I want to cast foo to type `Foo` and bar to type `Bar`. How can I do this?

I'm a complete beginner with Typescript. `groupBy` is the one from lodash package.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If Typescript can not deduce the type of the result of groupBy you could try asserting it yourself.

```js
function groupBy(o: any) {
    return o; // return any
}

let x = { a: 1, b: "1" }

// we know better than tsc and assert the type
let {a, b} = <{ a: number, b: string }>groupBy(x);
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: you should also check out the duplicate from artem, it's got a cleaner solution.

Comment: This will not always work because more complex objects will cause TS2352 (insufficient type overlap). ie `const {target} = <{target: HTMLInputElement}>mouseEvent`.